# Strange partial refresh behaviour

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have a custom control which is build out of 3 different parts.

- the menu bar
- the content table ( which is a repeat control )
- a footer

The content table is a repeat control in which another custom control is being rendered. Now I have the following xml:

```
<xp:table styleClass="lotusTable" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <xc:TimeGridBody id="timeGridBody"></xc:TimeGridBody>
    <xc:TimeGridFooter id="TimeGridFooter"></xc:TimeGridFooter>
</xp:table>
```

Within the timegrid there is a timeline custom control which has the following event handler

```
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onclick"
    submit="true"
    refreshMode="partial"
    execMode="partial"
    execId="timeLineRow"
    immediate="false" refreshId="timeLineRow">

    <xp:this.action>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:
            timeLineFactory.toDocument(compositeData.TimeLine);
            var editModeKey = "EditMode"+compositeData.TimeLine.getFdMe();
            viewScope.put(editModeKey, false);
        }]]>
    </xp:this.action>

    <xp:this.onComplete>
        <![CDATA[
            XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:TimeGridFooter}", {});
        ]]>
    </xp:this.onComplete>

</xp:eventHandler>
```

As you can see there is some stuff going on and when it is done it will refresh the timegridfooter control. I can see in my firebug that the partialrefresh get method is being executed and the return body of the call contains the refreshed data. But for some reason this data is NOT refresh on my browser. Can someone clarify me why this is happening? Is this because a partialrefreshget is being issues within a deeper part of the page ( aka different custom control)?

Comment: When the event script is rendered, does "#{id:TimeGridFooter}" get translated to the correct client ID?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was indeed a typo issue. Note to self: Don't code until it gets light again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a typo. After some good night sleep I checked it again and now it works.